# How to setup JanusGraph using Docker for Cassandra and Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, docker, cassandra, gremlin-server, janusgraph

I'm trying to setup JanusGraph for development on my local machine. My goal is to have a setup similar to the [Cassandra remote server mode](http://docs.janusgraph.org/latest/cassandra.html#_remote_server_mode_with_gremlin_server). As storage backend, I want to use Cassandra and as index backend I planned to use Elasticsearch.

For both, I'm using Docker containers ([Cassandra](https://hub.docker.com/_/cassandra/), [Elasticsearch](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docker.html)).

My `janusgraph-server.properties` file looks like this:

```
gremlin.graph=org.janusgraph.core.JanusGraphFactory
storage.backend=cassandra
storage.hostname=127.0.0.1
storage.cassandra.astyanax.cluster-name=cassandra_test_cluster

index.search.backend=elasticsearch
index.search.hostname=127.0.0.1
index.search.port=9300
index.search.elasticsearch.cluster-name=elasticsearch_test_cluster
```

Starting the gremlin-server leads to this failures:

```
0    [main] INFO  org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.GremlinServer  -
         \,,,/
         (o o)
-----oOOo-(3)-oOOo-----

162  [main] INFO  org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.GremlinServer  - Configuring Gremlin Server from conf/gremlin-server/gremlin-server.yaml
256  [main] INFO  org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.util.MetricManager  - Configured Metrics ConsoleReporter configured with report interval=180000ms
263  [main] INFO  org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.util.MetricManager  - Configured Metrics CsvReporter configured with report interval=180000ms to fileName=/tmp/gremlin-server-metrics.csv
343  [main] INFO  org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.util.MetricManager  - Configured Metrics JmxReporter configured with domain= and agentId=
345  [main] INFO  org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.util.MetricManager  - Configured Metrics Slf4jReporter configured with interval=180000ms and loggerName=org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.Settings$Slf4jReporterMetrics
800  [main] INFO  com.netflix.astyanax.connectionpool.impl.ConnectionPoolMBeanManager  - Registering mbean: com.netflix.MonitoredResources:type=ASTYANAX,name=ClusterJanusGraphConnectionPool,ServiceType=connectionpool
807  [main] INFO  com.netflix.astyanax.connectionpool.impl.CountingConnectionPoolMonitor  - AddHost: 127.0.0.1
884  [main] INFO  com.netflix.astyanax.connectionpool.impl.ConnectionPoolMBeanManager  - Registering mbean: com.netflix.MonitoredResources:type=ASTYANAX,name=KeyspaceJanusGraphConnectionPool,ServiceType=connectionpool
884  [main] INFO  com.netflix.astyanax.connectionpool.impl.CountingConnectionPoolMonitor  - AddHost: 127.0.0.1
1070 [main] INFO  org.janusgraph.graphdb.configuration.GraphDatabaseConfiguration  - Generated unique-instance-id=c0a8000424833-XXX-MacBook-Pro-local1
1078 [main] INFO  com.netflix.astyanax.connectionpool.impl.ConnectionPoolMBeanManager  - Registering mbean: com.netflix.MonitoredResources:type=ASTYANAX,name=ClusterJanusGraphConnectionPool,ServiceType=connectionpool
1079 [main] INFO  com.netflix.astyanax.connectionpool.impl.CountingConnectionPoolMonitor  - AddHost: 127.0.0.1
1082 [main] INFO  com.netflix.astyanax.connectionpool.impl.ConnectionPoolMBeanManager  - Registering mbean: com.netflix.MonitoredResources:type=ASTYANAX,name=KeyspaceJanusGraphConnectionPool,ServiceType=connectionpool
1082 [main] INFO  com.netflix.astyanax.connectionpool.impl.CountingConnectionPoolMonitor  - AddHost: 127.0.0.1
1099 [main] INFO  org.janusgraph.diskstorage.Backend  - Configuring index [search]
1179 [main] INFO  org.elasticsearch.plugins  - [General Orwell Taylor] loaded [], sites []
1655 [main] INFO  org.janusgraph.diskstorage.es.ElasticSearchIndex  - Configured remote host: 127.0.0.1 : 9300
1738 [elasticsearch[General Orwell Taylor][generic][T#2]] INFO  org.elasticsearch.client.transport  - [General Orwell Taylor] failed to get local cluster state for [#transport#-1][XXX-MacBook-Pro.local][inet[/127.0.0.1:9300]], disconnecting...
org.elasticsearch.transport.NodeDisconnectedException: [][inet[/127.0.0.1:9300]][cluster:monitor/state] disconnected
1743 [main] WARN  org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.GremlinServer  - Graph [graph] configured at [conf/gremlin-server/janusgraph-server.properties] could not be instantiated and will not be available in Gremlin Server.  GraphFactory message: GraphFactory could not instantiate this Graph implementation [class org.janusgraph.core.JanusGraphFactory]
java.lang.RuntimeException: GraphFactory could not instantiate this Graph implementation [class org.janusgraph.core.JanusGraphFactory]
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.structure.util.GraphFactory.open(GraphFactory.java:82)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.structure.util.GraphFactory.open(GraphFactory.java:70)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.structure.util.GraphFactory.open(GraphFactory.java:104)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.GraphManager.lambda$new$0(GraphManager.java:55)
    at java.util.LinkedHashMap$LinkedEntrySet.forEach(LinkedHashMap.java:671)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.GraphManager.<init>(GraphManager.java:53)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.util.ServerGremlinExecutor.<init>(ServerGremlinExecutor.java:83)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.GremlinServer.<init>(GremlinServer.java:110)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.GremlinServer.main(GremlinServer.java:344)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.structure.util.GraphFactory.open(GraphFactory.java:78)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not instantiate implementation: org.janusgraph.diskstorage.es.ElasticSearchIndex
    at org.janusgraph.util.system.ConfigurationUtil.instantiate(ConfigurationUtil.java:69)
    at org.janusgraph.diskstorage.Backend.getImplementationClass(Backend.java:477)
    at org.janusgraph.diskstorage.Backend.getIndexes(Backend.java:464)
    at org.janusgraph.diskstorage.Backend.<init>(Backend.java:149)
    at org.janusgraph.graphdb.configuration.GraphDatabaseConfiguration.getBackend(GraphDatabaseConfiguration.java:1850)
    at org.janusgraph.graphdb.database.StandardJanusGraph.<init>(StandardJanusGraph.java:134)
    at org.janusgraph.core.JanusGraphFactory.open(JanusGraphFactory.java:107)
    at org.janusgraph.core.JanusGraphFactory.open(JanusGraphFactory.java:87)
    ... 13 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.janusgraph.util.system.ConfigurationUtil.instantiate(ConfigurationUtil.java:58)
    ... 20 more
Caused by: org.elasticsearch.client.transport.NoNodeAvailableException: None of the configured nodes are available: []
    at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClientNodesService.ensureNodesAreAvailable(TransportClientNodesService.java:279)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClientNodesService.execute(TransportClientNodesService.java:198)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.support.InternalTransportClusterAdminClient.execute(InternalTransportClusterAdminClient.java:86)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.support.AbstractClusterAdminClient.health(AbstractClusterAdminClient.java:127)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.admin.cluster.health.ClusterHealthRequestBuilder.doExecute(ClusterHealthRequestBuilder.java:92)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.ActionRequestBuilder.execute(ActionRequestBuilder.java:91)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.ActionRequestBuilder.execute(ActionRequestBuilder.java:65)
    at org.janusgraph.diskstorage.es.ElasticSearchIndex.<init>(ElasticSearchIndex.java:215)
    ... 25 more
1745 [main] INFO  org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.util.ServerGremlinExecutor  - Initialized Gremlin thread pool.  Threads in pool named with pattern gremlin-*
2190 [main] INFO  org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.groovy.engine.ScriptEngines  - Loaded gremlin-groovy ScriptEngine
2836 [main] WARN  org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.groovy.engine.GremlinExecutor  - Could not initialize gremlin-groovy ScriptEngine with scripts/empty-sample.groovy as script could not be evaluated - javax.script.ScriptException: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: graph for class: Script1
```

`None of the configured nodes are available: []` why?
What can I do to make them available?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you verified whether Elasticsearch and Cassandra are running on those ports on localhost?  If not, I would recommend checking that you're forwarding to those ports when starting your containers.

I would also recommend checking the logs for Cassandra and Elasticsearch and seeing if there is any errors in those.

Comment: I had a look into the ElasticSearch logs (thanks for the hint) and found out, that there is a version conflict. The JanusGraph release 0.1.1 uses ElasticSearch v1.x.x and the Docker Image uses v5.x.x.

The current master from JanusGraph already supports ElasticSearch 5.x.x. I will either switch to master or use Solr as the search index backend.